# schedule timer for dialog in android

Tags: android, date, timer

I am in a situation where I need to display the Rate dialog based on the following flow

Open the app (First time )--> display dialog every 2 minutes

If rated --> display dialog next month

If clicked on later button --> display dialog next week.

```
String rate_value=myPref.getString("rate_value", "later");

        Log.e("rate", String.valueOf(rate_value));


        if (rate_value=="later") {

            initCalendarNextWeek();

            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            showRateDialog();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, nextWeekDate);
        }




        else if (rate_value=="now") {

            initCalendarNextMonth();

            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            showRateDialog();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }, nextMonthDate);
        }





        else if (rate_value=="no_thanks") {
            myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            showRateDialog();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }, 120000, 120000);
        }


public void initCalendarNextMonth(){
        cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_day=cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        cal_month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        cal_year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        nextMonthDate=new Date();
        nextMonthDate.setDate(cal_day);
        nextMonthDate.setMonth(cal_month+1);
        nextMonthDate.setYear(cal_year);
    }

    public void initCalendarNextWeek(){
        cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal_day=cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        cal_month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        cal_year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        nextWeekDate=new Date();
        nextWeekDate.setDate(cal_day+7);
        nextWeekDate.setMonth(cal_month);
        nextWeekDate.setYear(cal_year);
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem? is it showing nothing?

Comment: I am not sure with the date logic that I performed in initCalnder methods ...

Comment: Is this ok if I convert 7 days to milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so maybe look at Calendar class. The set methods of Date are deprecated so instead of using

`nextMonthDate = new Date()`

rather maybe use

`nextMonthDate = new Calendar();`

because then you can use the methods stated in the Calendar documentation such as add instead of using the setDate or setMonth. I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, also the method you are using are deprecated. Maybe use Calendar rather at least. (Things are usually deprecated for a reason). Also what variables are cal_day, cal_month etc because simply adding to it may actually run an int out of bounds of a date format.

Comment: Is this ok if I convert 7 days to milliseconds

Comment: also 30 days to milliseconds